# Setting default timezone does not work despite timezone being valid

Tags: php, timezone, centos, centos6

I'm geting when I just do phpinfo()

> Warning: phpinfo(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Europe/Helsinki' for 'EET/2.0/no DST' instead in /myadmin/i.php on line 8

here is i.php :

```
<?php
//echo date_default_timezone_get();

date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Kiev");

//echo date("l");

phpinfo();
?>
```

And as you can see, when I do date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Kiev") I get:

> Notice: date_default_timezone_set(): Timezone ID 'Europe/Kiev' is invalid in /myadmin/i.php on line 4

I'm sure I'm using valid timezone string from [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.europe.php), and I did set :

> date.timezone = Europe/Kiev

in php.ini file.

Environment: CentOS 6 , nginx/1.1.11 , PHP 5.3.8 (fpm-fcgi)

I really can't understand what's a matter.
Thank you.

Comment: What does `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Kiev');` return? It [should](http://nl3.php.net/date_default_timezone_set) return `true` on success and `false` on fail.

Comment: Do any other timezones work? Can you try the example given at http://php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.listidentifiers.php to print all supported timezones?

Comment: Somehow DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers() returns array(0) { }   HOW ?

Comment: "The latest version of the timezone database can be installed via PECL's » timezonedb."

Comment: there was some legal issue around the timezone db php uses (Olson DB). However I am not aware of that having any impact on PHP.

Comment: @futureboxlab could you move your "solution" section from your question into an answer and mark this question as answered? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to the comments, I was able to solve my problem. What I've done, in console:

```
#yum install php-pear

#pecl install timezonedb
```

It required c compiler:

```
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
```

...so I did:

```
#yum install gcc
```

Also,
if you get an error about the make command, simply run

```
#yum install make
```

Finally, try again:

```
#pecl install timezonedb
```

...it displays at the end:

```
You should add "extension=timezonedb.so" to php.ini
```

I added "extension=timezonedb.so" to /etc/php.ini, and restarted php-fpm:

```
#/etc/init.d/php-fpm restart
```

Comment: before run pecl, you need phpize, it wants php-devel to be installed
    #yum install php-devel

Answer (score 0):

To extend futureboxlab's solution, you may encounter another error regarding the 'make' command if you don't have make installed. 
In that case you'll just need to run

```
#yum install make
```

then, once again (third time's the charm)

```
#pecl install timezonedb
```