# change the time zone in config/app.php in laravel 5 on windows 8.1 machine

Tags: laravel-5, timezone

When I'm trying to change the timezone there to `'timezone' => 'UTC+5:30h'`, it will display an error like below.

> Notice: date_default_timezone_set(): Timezone ID 'UTC+5:30h' is invalid in...

How to solve it?

Comment: take a look at this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762608/setting-default-timezone-does-not-work-despite-timezone-being-valid

Comment: I'm working on windows. So yum in the command prompt not work. Can you help me please?

Comment: Well instead of 'timezone' => 'UTC +5:30h' try to do this - 'timezone' => 'Asia/Kolkatan'

Comment: Then it will display the same error as Notice: date_default_timezone_set(): Timezone ID 'Asia/Kolkatan' is invalid in D:\New-Sep-Project\New Sep Project\kids\kidsconer\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration.php on line 41

Comment: yeah sorry,just a misstype Kolkata ( no 'n' at the end) sorry for the issue

Comment: Thank you very much. It will work.

Comment: You're weclome,cheers :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107032/discussion-between-r-zoom-and-hrach).

Answer (score 1):

You should use this list: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php.
For example, for America the timezones are:

```
America/Adak - America/Anchorage - America/Anguilla - America/Antigua
America/Araguaina - America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires - 
America/Argentina/Catamarca - America/Argentina/Cordoba
America/Argentina/Jujuy - America/Argentina/La_Rioja - 
America/Argentina/Mendoza - America/Argentina/Rio_Gallegos
America/Argentina/Salta - America/Argentina/San_Juan - 
America/Argentina/San_Luis - America/Argentina/Tucuman
America/Argentina/Ushuaia - America/Aruba - America/Asuncion - 
America/Atikokan
America/Bahia - America/Bahia_Banderas - America/Barbados - America/Belem
America/Belize - America/Blanc-Sablon - America/Boa_Vista - America/Bogota
America/Boise - America/Cambridge_Bay - America/Campo_Grande - America/Cancun
America/Caracas - America/Cayenne - America/Cayman - America/Chicago
America/Chihuahua - America/Costa_Rica - America/Creston - America/Cuiaba
America/Curacao - America/Danmarkshavn - America/Dawson - America/Dawson_Creek
America/Denver - America/Detroit - America/Dominica - America/Edmonton
America/Eirunepe - America/El_Salvador - America/Fort_Nelson - America/Fortaleza
America/Glace_Bay - America/Godthab - America/Goose_Bay - America/Grand_Turk
America/Grenada - America/Guadeloupe - America/Guatemala - America/Guayaquil
America/Guyana - America/Halifax - America/Havana - America/Hermosillo
America/Indiana/Indianapolis - America/Indiana/Knox - America/Indiana/Marengo - America/Indiana/Petersburg
America/Indiana/Tell_City - America/Indiana/Vevay - America/Indiana/Vincennes - America/Indiana/Winamac
America/Inuvik - America/Iqaluit - America/Jamaica - America/Juneau
America/Kentucky/Louisville - America/Kentucky/Monticello - America/Kralendijk - America/La_Paz
America/Lima - America/Los_Angeles - America/Lower_Princes - America/Maceio
America/Managua - America/Manaus - America/Marigot - America/Martinique
America/Matamoros - America/Mazatlan - America/Menominee - America/Merida
America/Metlakatla - America/Mexico_City - America/Miquelon - America/Moncton
America/Monterrey - America/Montevideo - America/Montserrat - America/Nassau
America/New_York - America/Nipigon - America/Nome - America/Noronha
America/North_Dakota/Beulah - America/North_Dakota/Center - America/North_Dakota/New_Salem - America/Ojinaga
America/Panama - America/Pangnirtung - America/Paramaribo - America/Phoenix
America/Port-au-Prince - America/Port_of_Spain - America/Porto_Velho - America/Puerto_Rico America/Punta_Arenas - America/Rainy_River - America/Rankin_Inlet - America/Recife
America/Regina - America/Resolute - America/Rio_Branco - America/Santarem
America/Santiago - America/Santo_Domingo - America/Sao_Paulo - America/Scoresbysund
America/Sitka - America/St_Barthelemy - America/St_Johns - America/St_Kitts
America/St_Lucia - America/St_Thomas - America/St_Vincent - America/Swift_Current
America/Tegucigalpa - America/Thule - America/Thunder_Bay - America/Tijuana
America/Toronto - America/Tortola - America/Vancouver - America/Whitehorse
America/Winnipeg - America/Yakutat - America/Yellowknife
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if laravel accepts this parameter for the timezone, Try this format 'America/Chicago'. Replacing the value that match in your case.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.